# jQuery .get appends an unknown variable to URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm using this code as the starting point to an overhaul of our JavaScript framework:

```
$("#get").click(function(){
    $("#result").html(ajax_load);
    $.get(
        "http://www.google.com",
        {},
        function(responseText){
            $("#result").html(responseText);
        },
        "html"
    );
});
```

But when the request is made it includes a variable within the URL that I am unfarmiliar with, here is what Firebug says it's requesting:

```
http://www.google.com/?_=1268993359215
```

How do I get rid of this, when we target our internal scripts it's firing a 404 error :-(

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That parameter is used to force browser not to use cache.

You can not make `$.get` work without it explicitly, but you can use `$.ajax` instead:

```
$("#get").click(function(){
    $("#result").html(ajax_load);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.google.com",
        data: {},
        success: function(responseText) {
            $("#result").html(responseText);
        },
        cache: true,
        dataType: "html"
    });
});
```

Note the extra parameter `cache: true`. More on `$.ajax` here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Google was just an example, we can probably convert our internal scripts to prevent 404s :-), many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, before any $.get put this code

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
```

Answer (score 1):

Forcing the browser not to cache the target page is a good thing. Can you change your internal scripts to not 404 when extra GET variables are present? (It is a pretty strange way for them to behave)

Comment: Yes I can, this question was more about understanding the problem so I can make the correct decisions. Thanks :)